# Android emulator test

Tags: android, emulation

I am working on server-client architecture with mobile platforms and remote database.
I have a local server, then i coded android programs which are clients of my local server.

My computer has :

1. 8 GB ram
2. Windows 7 64 bit
3. Intel i7 2.93GHz

so i want to test my application with more emulator and i tried to open 10 or more emulator, but my computer could not.

Is there any way to trying more emulator to test my application?
I need 10 or more testing client machine on local

Comment: How are you opening the client emulators? Are there 10 individual emulators created by the AVD manager or it is one emulator you wish to open 10 times.

Comment: 10 individual emulators created by the AVD manager, and i want to open all emulators at the same time

Comment: waooh, its too much even for a quad core i7 especially when using the latest version of the android ADT and running all kit kat virtual devices. However, i will try to suggest an answer and post it. Give it some time.

Comment: Why do you need 10 clients to test the application?

Comment: i mean, 10 or more because i' ll send some information and images from the node.js at the same time, also a client can change the data which has to shown by another clients. So i want to test whole system cause this is so critical, it will be a medical system. on the other hand i dont want to create a server for now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would look into commercial emulators such as [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) or using a [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) accelerated emulator

Answer (score 1):

Ok, A thing to try would be to run 4 virtual machine using the vmware software. Each emulator can then run a like 3 virtual devices then connect to your main host and test your app. All the virtual machines would connect to the host's local network with minimal configuration. From there, each of the virtual devices running on the virtual machines can have access to the host's local network.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

1. Be sure you're running [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) as [mach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233048/mach) mentioned above.
2. If the bottleneck is a RAM limitation, thus try to increase the SWAP size in Windows System settings, but take into account, this will dramatically decrease the overall system performance, especially if 
   you have HDD and not SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Genymotion and blue stacks and Intel HAXM and default emulator so that you can reach your count.:-)